# Why project freeze after first send/get?

Tags: python, sockets

I have this simple server-client project. Its connect and I can get data from server but only first time. If I try to get data again it stops. Can anyone help me, whats wrong with my code?

## This method get text from entry, send it to server and get the response. This method belongs to client class

```
def getMessage(self,clSocket):
        clSocket.send(self.input.get().encode("ASCII"))
        messageFromServer=clSocket.recv(128)
        messagebox.showinfo("answer", messageFromServer)
```

## Main

```
def main(): 
    serverName="localhost"
    serverPort=11000
    clientSocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = client(root,clientSocket)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the response is 128 bytes long? It looks like the server is trying to send you more data but you ignore it. For a server such behaviour is most probably unexpected, so the transmission hangs.

Comment: No, 128 is fine. Im getting the desired response but in next request it stops

Comment: Still, have you tried reading past those 128 without performing a new `send()`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have not got enough code for it to work accurately, and you do not have a repeater, so it works by connecting it and sending across a message, then because it has not repeater to keep the connection open, it cuts the connection.
Edit: Your code has zero functionality as you are only putting the client code up and asking us to build you a functioning project. You have to give us your attempt to build a server so it can latch onto it. Also for you localhost, you can simply replace it with socket.gethostname() and that will work for the local host.

Comment: Can you suggest anything how to do the repeater? It wont work if I put inside while True

Comment: Simply put, the code in your question can not work as a repeating message as it has a few fundamentals that are not put in, if that is your code then I would suggest looking more in depth in researching how to make sockets, either way I'll update my answer to make it repeating

Comment: Sorry, but without having your server code, I can not find a way to make it loop.